# PageStorageKey for AssetsAudioPlayer?

Tags: flutter

I use this plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player). I can hear the voice, there is no issue here. I use bottomnavbar and I have 3 pages. I use this plugin in a page, when I reenter this page this voice resets (initState). How can I fix this issue?

I want to keep the voice or page when I change the page, is this possible?

I tried GlobalKey but I couldn't fix it.

By the way, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new class for AssetsAudioPlayer. I keep my _assetsAudioPlayer variable. So I can keep all about my voice.